# Package for accessing Cassandra database in R

Tags: software-development, java, database, data

I have tried [RCassandra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCassandra/) and [RJDBC](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/big-analytics-with-r-cassandra-and-hive) but unfortunately it seems that these bindings work only with the old Cassandra 1.x. Is there any binding for Cassandra 2.x in *R* language?